# Identifying $\mathbb H^n$ with $\mathbb C^{2n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quaternions

Let $X \in M_n(\mathbb H)$ (Hermetian field).

It is possible to make $\mathbb H^n$ into a $2n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$, for example, by embedding $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb H$ as the following subfields:

- $\mathbb R1+\mathbb Ri$
- $\mathbb R1+\mathbb Rj$
- $\mathbb R1+\mathbb Rk$

where $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$

Here is what I need to do: I need to write out the corresponding matrix of $X$ as an element of $M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$, and if possible show that the trace of $X$ is independent of the choice.

Here is what I got so far and got stuck with:

For example, using the first of these embedding, it is possible to write $\mathfrak z = x+jy \in \mathbb H ^n$ with $x,y \in \mathbb C^n$, and likewise $C=A+jB \in M_n(\mathbb H)$, with $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb C)$.

If so, the maps $\mathfrak z \rightarrow \left( \begin{smallmatrix} a\\ c \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ and  $C \rightarrow \left( \begin{smallmatrix} A&-\bar B\\  B&\bar A \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ identify $\mathbb H$$^n$ with $\mathbb C^{2n}$ and $M_n(\mathbb H)$ with the real subalgebra of $M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$ consisting of matrices $T$ such that $JT=\bar TJ$, where $J = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&I\\  -I&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.

How can I continue this and find the corresponding matrix of $X$ as an element of $M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$, and  show that the trace of $X$ is independent of the choice?

Comment: So $\Bbb{H}$ is the algebra of (Hamilton's) quaternions?

Comment: Indeed. I've seen it reffered to as Hermetian field, but also as Quaternions. I'll believe you it's Hamiltion's

Comment: [This en.Wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Classical_group#Matrix_groups_over_non-commutative_rings) might be interesting in this context.